# Ccache not growing over 1GB with max size = 30GB when compiling AOSP 8.1

Tags: android, android-source, ccache

I'm compiling AOSP 8.1.0 source tree on my build server. I made a docker image with all packages needed from Ubuntu 16.04. I mount the source tree, ANDROID_OUT and ccache dir when starting docker image. The path in docker for these three directories is the same:

Sources: /home/builder/android_source/AOSP_8.1/

Out: /home/builder/android_out/AOSP_8.1/

ccache: /home/builder/ccache/

The question is that I don't understand how ccache behaves. 
If I'm running `watch ccache -s` while compiling android, I see something like:

```
files in cache: 10365
cache size: 931.9MB
```

And some seconds after these values can either increase or decrease. I've set max cache size to 30GB, `ccache -s` tells me this correct max size, but cache size never comes over 1Gb. The maximum size I've seen after 5 builds run after each other is about 983MB.

What I tried?

1) `chown -R builder:builder ~/ccache/`

2) `ccache -M 30G` in docker. Max sized sets to 30GB, behavior remains the same.

3) `ccache -C` - cache clears, nothing gets better.

What is wrong with my ccache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some strange reason this situation was due to some incompatibility between system ccache and android ccache. After doing

```
ccache -M 50G
```

with ccache utility from android sources directory everything is working.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is still interested the answer is this:

Android:
prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 50GB
stores 50GB as 50*65536 in your /0 to f/stats in line 15.

Gnu:
/usr/bin/ccache tool keeps as stated in the manual in your:
/ccache.conf (typically /etc/ccache.conf or /usr/local/etc/ccache.conf )
or /ccache.conf (typically $HOME/.ccache/ccache.conf)
as human english text:
max_size = 50GB

So each tool keeps it in diferent place. But the android one doesn't have a manual.

Comment: What does `/0 to f/stats in line 15` mean?

Comment: `/0 to f/stats in line 15` means that in the CCACHE_DIR there are directories `0/`..`f/`.  Each has a `stats` file that keeps statistics *and* the `max_size` and `max_files` configuration.  `max_size` is line 15 of the `stats` file and `max_files` is line 14.  This applies to ccache 3.1.9 - I'm not sure if it applies to all other versions.  The AOSP build uses the `ccache` binary in `./prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache`.  The source for that prebuilt is in a tarball there as well.